# How to uninstall VMware add-in from visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vmware, add-in, visual-studio-addins

Hi
I've VMware Workstation 6.5.2 installed on my PC.
This program's add-in, use assign F6 key to one of its commands. 
The problem is that when ever I reassign F6 key to BuildSolution command, after reopening VS, the add-in change my settings and reassign it to its command again...
What I have to do?!
Is it possible to uninstall this add-in? (The Startup CheckBox in Visual Studio Add-in Manager is disabled for this program...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate that too! ;) I discovered this is a custom / advanced configuration option of the VMware Workstation installer. You might have to uninstall it, then install it again but be sure to choose the advanced mode that lets you choose various options.

Comment: The question is, how and why the Startup checkbox in Visual Studio Add-in manager is disabled?!

Answer (score 7):

I just ran the installer again for "Modify/Change" and remove the "Visual Studio Plugin". After that, the vmware menu and debugger is removed from my VS.

Comment: In my case, "Modify/Change" is disabled. I opened up RegEdit, and searched for VMDebugger. I deleted all the results. My VS doesn't have the menu anymore.